# PHP Curl, global timeout issue when redirections

Tags: php, redirect, curl, timeout

I'm having an issue with the global Curl timeout.

The following param is working fine when there is no redirection on an url :

```
curl_setopt($ch[$n_result], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 29);
```

The connexion is closed after 29 seconds if the target doesn't answer in time.

But when there is one, or several redirections, this timeout value is not handled anymore :

total time : 52.116
redir_time : 51.9511
redir_count : 1

I'm using these params to setup my limits, and using a Curl multi instances :

```
curl_setopt($ch[$n_result], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch[$n_result], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch[$n_result], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 29);
curl_setopt($ch[$n_result], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 29);
```

Did you already have this kind of issue, and do you know how to fix an hard limit to 29s for example, for all the transaction, including redirections ?

Thank you very much in advance guys :)

Simon

Comment: remove the followlocation option, and make it manually, using cookies.

Comment: Thx for your answer hassan, but not sure to get you here. Do you mean, keep all datas in a cookie, and reuse it to make a manual redirection by exec again a new Curl session on the target page ?
Or there is a magic stuff to set in a cookie to auto follow the redirection ?

Comment: there is no magic there, as you said , you will kind of do a simulation , something like follows: (1) make a curl session 1 , (2) get it's cookies in a file, (3) send this cookies to curl session 2

Comment: yeah, what I though unfortunately. Do you know if it's an issue on Curl php ?